# DynamoDB - Update Map Object by appending Another Map Object to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update a Map Object in DynamoDB by adding another map object to it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141206/how-to-put-a-new-key-value-pair-into-a-map-in-dynamodb-java) they add a single key value pair to a map. I want to add multiple key value pairs to a map in one request. There should be something like map_append similar to list_append. How can I do this? I went through the docs but could not find anything similar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use multiple SET update expressions separated by commas, following the example of the [question you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141206/how-to-put-a-new-key-value-pair-into-a-map-in-dynamodb-java). `SET map.#number1 = :string1, map.#number2 = :string2, map.#number3 = :string3`

Comment: thank you! such a simple solution and it works like a charm :)