# Add element to end of a list - AWS DB from Android

Tags: android, list, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a list item within AWS NoSQL DB.

I want to add a String value to the end of that list. My code is the following:

```
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> primaryKey = new HashMap<>();
                AttributeValue key = new AttributeValue()
                        .withS(Array1[x]);
                AttributeValue range = new AttributeValue()
                        .withS(Array2[x]);
                primaryKey.put("XXXXX", key);
                primaryKey.put("XXXXX", range);

                try {
                    UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest()
                            .withTableName("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                            .withKey(primaryKey)
                            .addAttributeUpdatesEntry(
                                    "groups", new AttributeValueUpdate()
                                    .withValue(new AttributeValue().withS(groupID))
                                    .withAction(AttributeAction.ADD));
                    dynamoDBClient.updateItem(request);
```

Unsurprisingly this just overwrites the entire list in the AWS DB with the string rather than adding a new element to the list.

Is there anyway to do this without having to download the whole list, adding the string and then re-uploading? Would be allot cleaner to just ask that a new element is added to the end of the list.

Comment: You tagged this question with [tag:amazon-simpledb] yet you appear to be using [tag:amazon-dynamodb].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out if anyone is having a similar issue.

Rather than trying to add an element to the "groups" field which is a list I changed the field in DynamoDB to a string set and adjusted the code as follows:

```
try {
                    UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest()
                            .withTableName("XXXXXXXXXXX")
                            .withKey(primaryKey)
                            .addAttributeUpdatesEntry(
                                    "groups", new AttributeValueUpdate()
                                    .withValue(new AttributeValue().withSS(groupID))
                                    .withAction(AttributeAction.ADD));
                    dynamoDBClient.updateItem(request);
```

This now adds a new element to the end of the string set

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're are actually looking for this:

```
    UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest();
    request.setTableName("myTableName");
    request.setKey(Collections.singletonMap("hashkey",
            new AttributeValue().withS("my_key")));
    request.setUpdateExpression("list_append(:prepend_value, my_list)");
    request.setExpressionAttributeValues(
            Collections.singletonMap(":prepend_value",
                    new AttributeValue().withN("1"))
    );
    dynamodb.updateItem(request);
```

Example taken from: [How to update a Map or a List on AWS DynamoDB document API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265355/how-to-update-a-map-or-a-list-on-aws-dynamodb-document-api)